# Converting existing C project to WPF

Tags: c++, c, wpf, windows, upgrade

I want to redesign the UI for a pre-existing, working C project. It's not Visual Studio, it's plain .c and .h files. The changes I intend on making will require WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation).

I'm wondering if this is possible, and if so, how difficult it would be. Any links to tutorials, etc. would be fantastic. I can read and write C at a novice-intermediate level, but I'm very new to Visual Studio stuff.

Comment: This really depends on how your current project is implemented, are you following MVC?

Comment: Specifically, this is the project: https://github.com/noodle1983/putty-nd I highly doubt it follows MVC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the best approach for this type of work is to:

1. Decouple the logic from the UI in the existing code base.
2. Make a P/Invoke (C API) or C++/CLI wrapper for the logic
3. Use C# to build the WPF front end for this.